# Init process at 2000% CPU usage

Tags: 16.04, cpu, init

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine and recently I found that the init process is at 2000% CPU usage and it would restart with the same cpu usage after killing it. This occurred after I updated my graphics driver. Since I'm totally new to Ubuntu, I have no idea what's going on. Tracking the process using strace and I found that 'init' is reapeatedly calling 'epoll_wait function'. Can anybody help me solve this?
[image: cpu usage]

[image: output of strace]

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. The 'init' process is in fact a crypto-mining process, not the system process init. I deleted the malware and now everything has back to normal.

Comment: How did you find out it's a crypto mining process?